# How to create tabs on SharePoint page?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to create tabs on SharePoint aspx page? I don't want to create links on the navigation bar. I am interested to have tabs on the page, so that i can put different contents on different tabs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box, no. You'll have to develop your own javascript which makes it possible or find a 3rd party component which supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple JQuery plugin to achieve this:

- Give reference of JQuery and this Plugin on your page
- Create different divs
- Add content to different tabs

Please check [this](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) link

Comment: However, please be advised the JQuery UI will not support the SharePoint Themes

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hillbilly Tabs in SharePoint Modern. I fork a repository from hillbilly and modified some parts. I just followed the idea from here

[Hillbilly Tabs](https://tipsbybits.com/other/custom-tabs-hillbilly-tabs-in-modern-sharepoint/)